# Tackling Addictions Directly VS Meditation

Tags: meditation-practicalities, right-effort

I gathered some ideas from different previous replies, but I thought I'd synthesize these ideas into a question.

Is it (1) more sensible to cut down on addictive behaviours *in order to* liberate one's time for meditation, or (2) meditate despite addictive behaviours present *as to* cause their diminution.

In other words, will addictive behaviours diminish naturally from a meditation practice? Or, will diminishing addictions and procrastination and such enable meditation?

Personally, I feel my attempts at diminishing attachments have generated very few effortful and beneficial behaviours. It seems the other way around: meditation, exercise, reading all *lead* to more efficient time-spending.

If this is so, then it seems to imply diminishing *all* attachments is less beneficial than tackling gross aversion to effort. Any thoughts?

Thank you.

(Extra thought: can we say expending effort involves a process of *becoming*, given there's an investment producing effects? In this sense, effortful activities like those I mention have a karmic -- i.e. efficient -- effect, while detachment involves removing oneself from karma. For example, I could exercise and produce a good result, but by avoiding junk food I am *avoiding* negative consequences. Just a thought!)

Answer (score 2):

The hindrence here is Sceptical doubt (*vicikiccha*), which is the cause of not taking on the right practice.

For the purpose of release: Not-knowing (right) is the cause of addiction, *tanha*, Eggmann.

By reminderless up-rooting of this very not-knowing (*avijjā*), there is the end of suffering, the end of grasping after this and that.

And how is the path for up-rooting this very root of suffering? Just this Noble eightfold path, with right view as it's for-runner.

And what is the prerequisite to develop right view?

- [Faith](http://www.zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/nyanaponika/devotion_en.html)
- [Association with People of Integrity](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/study/into_the_stream_en.html#association)
- [Listening to the True Dhamma](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/study/into_the_stream_en.html#listening)
- [Appropriate Attention](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/study/into_the_stream_en.html#attention)
- [Practice in Accordance with the Dhamma](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/study/into_the_stream_en.html#practice)

Not released now one might think: "**I know**, but..." In that case there there was the case of improper attention by not having had admirable association out of lack of devotion, out of lack of faith. In that case, if not willing to uproot this by approaching the Juwels in the right way, find access to them by lowering, by giving up, by seeking refuge, there is no way, no short cut that right view could be developed, right release be gained. For such as "knowing" and still doubt, such can not be.

That was why it was sad: "For the purpose of release: Not-knowing (right) is the cause of addiction, *tanha*, Eggmann."

And what is the cause, what is the reason for faith? Suffering, being confronted to give up, to seek for release, is the reason why one takes on faith.

For one havving gained right view, had attended proper, listened proper, seen and reminds the Dhamma, just then:

> **[The Tree Pulls Itself Down](http://www.zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/thai/chah/insimpleterms_en.html)**
>
> Craving and desire lead us to suffering. But if we contemplate, our contemplation leans out from craving. It contemplates craving, and it pulls on the craving, shakes it up, so that it goes away or lessens on its own.
>
> It's like a tree. Does anyone tell it what to do? Does anyone give it hints? You can't tell it what to do. You can't make it do anything. But it leans over and pulls itself down. When you look at things in this way, that's Dhamma.

So focus on gaining right view, it's pre-requisites. For it is not pleasant to be sooner or later confronted with suffering, when sickness, death, lose of beloved, gain of pain... arises and one does not find the way to release, does not know, have not discerned, seen before, here and now.

**Asking:** Tackling Addictions Directly or Meditation:

[Respect, Confidence and Patient](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,8233.msg13242.html#msg13242) as prerequisite means for release from addiction, when and before is effects come into be.

And what are the obstacles,

[the Hindrances for devotion, for lowering, Individually](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/nyanaponika/wheel026_en.html#top)?

- 1. Sensual Desire
- 2. Ill-will
- 3. Sloth and Torpor
- 4. Restlessness and Remorse
- 5. Doubt

May all beings find the way to end suffering by themselves with ease!

---

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma and not meant for commercial purpose and other low wordily gains by means of trade and exchange]*

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a combination of both. Obvious unwholesome & dangerous addictions can be overcome directly, without meditation, because the mind should ideally discern these addictions are very harmful & very dangerous.

But with more subtle & ordinary addictions (such as eating wrong & too much food, watching lots of TV or even sex), meditation can provide the alternative source of pleasure to replace these sensual addictions.

In Buddhism, it seems clear that people need pleasure or happiness and that one of the benefits of meditation is it can provide a stable source of non-sensual pleasure.